# delete from database in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

```
$this->Attrriskcontrol->deleteAll(
    array(
       'Attrriskcontrol.assessid'=>'$assess_id',
       'Attrriskcontrol.controlid'=>'$control_id'
   ));
```

I want to delete where the value is assessid and controlid in the database. How should i put the values in `$assess_id` and `$control_id`?

And is this the right query to delete?

Comment: remove the quotes around the variables

Comment: just remove quotes from $assess_id and $control_id

`$this->Attrriskcontrol->deleteAll(array('Attrriskcontrol.assessid'=> $assess_id, 'Attrriskcontrol.controlid'=>$control_id))`

Comment: $assess_id = $this->Attrriskcontrol->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Attrriskcontrol.assessid')));
       $control_id = $this->Attrriskcontrol->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Attrriskcontrol.controlid'))); - this is how I am selecting assessid and controlid from model Attrriskcontrol. Still showing error